# Set language of template in Django by clicking on <a> link from Bootstrap Dropdown menu

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

In Django's documentation there's an [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#django.views.i18n.set_language) that shows how a user can choose the language of the page. They fill  and then submit a form.

This example works for me. However, I'd like to use a [Bootstrap dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)  with a list of  links to cause this behaviour. I have the idea to set the value of the "next" input to the code of the chosen language and submit the form. Here's the code:

```
<form name="ui" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    {% get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as lang %}
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
    {{ lang.name_local }}
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {% for language in languages %}
        <li><a href="#" onclick="document.ui.next.value='{{ language.code}}'; document.ui.submit();">{{ language.name_local }}</a></li>                                                                    
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</form>
```

It generates the following html code (I left out csrf token, but it's there):

```
<form name="ui" action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="" />
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">English<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.ui.next.value='en'; document.ui.submit();">English</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.uiLang.next.value='de'; document.uiLang.submit();">German</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</form>
```

This leads (choosing German with "de" language code), however, to 404 error with Request URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/i18n/setlang/de (and, don't no why, with Request Method "GET").

What went wrong and how can I solve the problem?

p.s. The line

```
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

is there in urls.py

Answer (score 7):

This is what works for me: adding an additional input element with the name "language"

Further, assign a language code for it in JS before submitting the form, i.e. document..language.value =

Then the part of template looks like this:

```
<form name="ui" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
<input name="language" type="hidden"/>
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as lang %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{{ lang.name_local }}
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
{% for language in languages %}
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.ui.language.value='{{ language.code}}'; document.ui.submit();">{{ language.name_local }}</a></li>                                                                    
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: The solution is great! Thank you for sharing. You've foggoten a closing tag `</form>`

Answer (score 4):

you can try this easier one:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_available_languages as languages %}

{% for language in languages %}
    <li class="{% ifequal current_language language.0 %}active{% endifequal %}">
        <a href="/./{{ language.0 }}/" title="{{ language.1 }}">
            {{ language.1 }}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: how is {{ lang }} defined?

Comment: what is current_language? {% get_current_language as current_language %}, right?

Comment: @MaxLi its in the docs:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates

Comment: I might have missed something, but I don't see there a variable "current_language" showing up, only "get_current_language". You use it in the block {% ifequal current_language language.0 %}

Comment: I found the solution that works for me and posted it as an answer. Your solution didn't work for me, may be it depends on other settings. Anyway, thanks for collaboration, it led me to other ideas, thus, an upvote from me for it.

Answer (score 1):

@doniyor an slightly modified version of your answer (consider using i18n context_processor )

```html
{% with "/"|add:LANGUAGE_CODE as redundant %}
  {% for language_code, _ in LANGUAGES %}
    {% if language_code != LANGUAGE_CODE %}
      <li>
        <a class="text-decoration-none dropdown-item archive-link"
           href="/{{ language_code }}{{ request.get_full_path|cut:redundant }}">
           {{ language_code|language_name_local }} ({{ language_code }})
        </a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```